# Getting "Unbound record field mid_x"

Tags: syntax, ocaml, record

I am not understanding why I am getting this error: `Unbound record field mid_x` when running this code. What the function `midpoint_segment` is trying to do is find the midpoint of a given type segment and return a point type.

```
type point = 
  {x : float; y : float} 

type segment = 
  {startp : point; endp : point}

let midpoint_segment {startp; endp} =
  let mid_x = (startp.x +. endp.x) /. 2.0 in
  let mid_y = (startp.y +. endp.y) /. 2.0 in
  {mid_x; mid_y}
```

What does this error mean? I am defining `mid_x` and `mix_y` with `let`.

Answer (score 3):

`{mid_x; mid_y}` is syntax sugar for the record literal `{mid_x = mid_x; mid_y = mid_y}`.

If you want to create a record of type `point` you either need to specify the record field labels explicitly: `{x = mid_x; y = mid_y}` or, to use field punning, rename `mid_x` and `mid_y` to `x` and `y` in order to do `{x; y}`.

Comment: I often add a constructor: `let point x y = {x; y}` and then you would write `point mid_x mid_y`

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow outside of an abstract type situation where it's necessary, it doesn't seem like much of a gain vs. `{x=mid_x; y=mid_y}`.

Comment: @Chris It's quite useful when you have multiple records with the same label. Or at least is was crucial, now ocaml can kind of guess what record you mean if you have some unique label in there.